# how to get parameter in REST web service from curl?

Tags: java, rest, curl, parameters, request

if the user request in curl like curl -u username:password .
I wonder how to get parameter from curl -u in REST web service?Do any know?
I use jersey framework using java. I use Netbean IDE and glassfish server.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the HttpServletRequest method [getUserPrincipal](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) and/or [getRemoteUser](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

Remember these methods will only return the username for authenticated requests.